# Problem in handling split method in python

Tags: python, split

I am trying to split the name of text-file which have string and numeric part but it is showing error.Please find the code below.

```
#getting class name
    for file in os.listdir(path):
        i,j = file.split('_')
        j = int(j.split('.')[0])
        label.append(i)
        doc_num.append(j)
```

error message below

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-20-16cacda50bba> in <module>
----> 1 doc_num, label, email, subject, text = preprocessing(cwd)

<ipython-input-19-95e2b6ddf98e> in preprocessing(path)
      9     #getting class name
     10     for filename in os.listdir(path):
---> 11         i,j = filename.split('_')
     12         j = int(j.split('.')[0])
     13         label.append(i)

ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)
```

my file name is "alt.atheism_49960", spliting file_name on basis of "_" present, want the result to be stored in this and this way alt.atheism & 49960

Comment: If that error comes from *i,j = filename.split('_')* then *filename* does **not** contain an underscore. I suggest you add *print(filename)* before attempting the *split()*

Comment: maybe you have more files in `path` directory (or more directories) that doesn't have `_` in their name

Comment: I have checked the whole folder where all the files are in the same format as i have mentioned  "alt.atheism_49960"

Comment: In have checked the path by running os.getcwd() and checked the file name

Comment: when i am performing the split on single filename it is working fine, but not working on single file.

Comment: @himanshumangoli Did you add *print(filename)* before the split as per my suggestion? What did it show? Some debugging would be very helpful here

Comment: @Fred yes i did the same, problem has resolved it is due to problem in the dataset.